# How do I combine a bunch of xaml-based vector image files into a single dictionary?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Is there a facility for automatically converting and combining several xaml-based objects into a single ResourceDictionary in VS, Blend or even third-party app. Here's a vector image file I would like turned into a resource:

```
<Canvas Width="94.936523" Height="177.207031" Name="AmericanImage">
    <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="F1 M 67.072266,6.236816 C 67.069336,6.233398 68.373047,2.524414 71.210938,2.522949 C 71.210938,2.521484 75.245117,2.520996 75.248047,2.520996 C 75.248047,2.521484 79.283203,2.521484 79.284180,2.523926 C 82.116211,2.525391 83.424805,6.233887 83.422852,6.238281 C 83.425781,6.269043 84.953125,42.543457 84.953125,42.543457 L 65.763672,42.540527 C 65.763672,42.540527 67.072266,6.241699 67.072266,6.236816 Z"/>
</Canvas>
```

It would be nice to right-click on the file and select something like "Add to dictionary..." and it would automatically add a Key and insert it into the data dictionary either inlined or linked to a file. Is there anything like this?  It's hard to believe that ResourceDictionaries have to be built manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few possible ways:

1) Use of data template
You are packing your image in DataTemplate and then use like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TheIcon">
    <Canvas Width="94.936523" Height="177.207031" Name="AmericanImage">
       <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="F1 M 67.072266,6.236816 C 67.069336,6.233398 68.373047,2.524414 71.210938,2.522949 C 71.210938,2.521484 75.245117,2.520996 75.248047,2.520996 C 75.248047,2.521484 79.283203,2.521484 79.284180,2.523926 C 82.116211,2.525391 83.424805,6.233887 83.422852,6.238281 C 83.425781,6.269043 84.953125,42.543457 84.953125,42.543457 L 65.763672,42.540527 C 65.763672,42.540527 67.072266,6.241699 67.072266,6.236816 Z"/>
     </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

And then use like this

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TheIcon}"/>
```

2)Almost same approach, but you save in dictionary only **Geometry**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <Geometry x:Key="Geometry">
            F1 M 67.072266,6.236816 C 67.069336,6.233398 68.373047,2.524414 71.210938,2.522949 C 71.210938,2.521484 75.245117,2.520996 75.248047,2.520996 C 75.248047,2.521484 79.283203,2.521484 79.284180,2.523926 C 82.116211,2.525391 83.424805,6.233887 83.422852,6.238281 C 83.425781,6.269043 84.953125,42.543457 84.953125,42.543457 L 65.763672,42.540527 C 65.763672,42.540527 67.072266,6.241699 67.072266,6.236816 Z
        </Geometry>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

and usage:

```
<Canvas Width="94.936523" Height="177.207031" Name="AmericanImage">
  <Path Data="{StaticResource Geometry}"/>
</Canvas>
```

also you can pack solution **#2** into custom control.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I databind the image to a control ?  Let's say I have a list of products in a database  and their vector images are in a dictionary.  How do I dynamically bind product A with image B?